# Retrieve AngularJS app name

Tags: angularjs

How can I retrive the name of the current app in AngularJS?
I mean the `ng-app="foo"` value.
I have searched through the API documentation, but I could not find any reference to this.

**MY SOLUTION**
Actually I have found solution like this

```
angular.element($('[ng-app]')).attr('ng-app');
```

But I don't really like the idea to search through DOM just to get this information.
Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [$rootElement](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootElement) docs:

> The root element of Angular application. This is either
>   the element where ngApp was declared or the element passed into
>   angular.bootstrap.

If you inject it you can get the main module name without scanning the DOM:

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
```

```js
app.controller('MyCtrl',
  [
    '$scope', 
    '$rootElement', 
    function($scope, $rootElement) {
      console.log($rootElement.attr('ng-app')); // --> myApp
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Can I retrieve the $rootElement from a angular service? I need it there, but I don't have a $scope variable in my service.

Comment: Simply inject it into your service, the same way you would inject it into controllers. You don't need $scope.

Comment: I wasn't able to inject it since I used .service instead of .factory to create my service. Everything works fine now. Thanks!