# find out angular app name from Directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which can be used in several applications, and I would like to be able to log the apps using the directive.
How can I find out the app name that is including the directive, if I can at all?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502055/retrieve-angularjs-app-name