# Angular, get app or module name dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have an SPA developed in Angular and I want to fire my analytics code when the router changes, so I want to be able to get the app name or the module name. Below is the code I am trying to use but I am getting error as "ReferenceError: testApp is not defined(…)".

```
function getAllElementsWithAttribute(attribute)
 {
   var matchingElements = [];
   var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
   for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++)
   {
     if (allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute) !== null)
     {
       // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
       matchingElements.push(allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute));
      }
   }
  return matchingElements[0];
 }

if(window.angular != undefined || window.angular != null){
   console.log("Angular lOADED");
   //var modName = angular.modules[0];  

   var modName = getAllElementsWithAttribute("ng-app"); 
   try{
     var myMod = typeof(eval(modName));
     console.log(myMod);            
   }catch(e){
     console.log(e);
  }

  myMod.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    console.log($routeScope)
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {     
     if(true){
        loadTag($location);
     }
   });
 });

  function loadTag(location){
    console.log(location);
    console.log("Tag Loaded");
  }
}
```

Comment: you can to use require.js to load by demand. Look that documentation, specially about modules: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can do the "names" definition on the route configuration like this:

```
.state('dummy', {
        url: '/dummy',
        templateUrl: 'app/dummy.html',
        controller: 'DummyController',
        MyModuleOrTag: 'dummyTAg'
      })
```

And you can get like this:

```
$state.current.MyModuleOrTag
```

I think in this way will be faster what search of each element

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for the response but forgive my knowledge, I am pretty new to Angular, and there are lot of applications and I am not aware how many pages or what pages are there. So I want to fire my code in such a way that it should get the module pr app name and on routechangesuccess I'll get the page name and baed on that I''ll fire my tags. I hope this clarifies...

Comment: Have you saw this? [retrieve-angularjs-app-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502055/retrieve-angularjs-app-name), in AngularJS we have access to [$rootElement](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootElement). In this element you can find the app name, but about the module i don't think its possible to retreive

Comment: Yes, but I want to fire my code dynamically when the router changes, how do I achieve that